# How to write PID to file in Python?

Tags: python, crud, pid

I get the current running script PID by `os.getpid()`, and try to store it in a file but I get an error that `write()` only accepts 'string' and not 'int'. So how to pass PID as a string to `write()`?

My code:

```
import os

outputFile = open('test.txt', "w")
pid = os.getpid()
outputFile.write(pid)
outputFile.close()
```

Comment: `outputFile.write(str(pid))`

Comment: You can convert it to string with `str`. Also, you may consider working with files with `with` key-word. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/with-statement-in-python/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have to use type convertor `str()` like this:

```py
import os

with open('test.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(str(os.getpid()))
```